# Merge array according to key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've got a huge list of arrays with 2 members which looks like that:

```
<?php
$aData = array ();
$aData[0] = array ( 14400, 'Item1' );
$aData[1] = array ( 14400, 'Item4' );
$aData[2] = array ( 14401, 'Item2' );
$aData[3] = array ( 14402, 'Item4' );
$aData[4] = array ( 14402, 'Item5' );
$aData[5] = array ( 14402, 'Item9' );
```

and I'd like to convert this into arrays like that:

```
$aData[0] = array ( 14400, 'Item1,Item4' );
$aData[1] = array ( 14401, 'Item4' );
$aData[2] = array ( 14402, 'Item4,Item5,Item9' );
```

Whereas the 2nd one could be a string or an array.
Now I was trying to implement some logic - but is there a function that could do that at least partly?
`array_map` or `array_merge_recursive` don't seem to fit exactly?

Comment: Oh .. sorry - totally forgot the language

Comment: Can you give us the array?
Is it like this? $array = array('14400'=>'Item1','14400'=>'Item4','14401'=>'Item2','14402'=>'Item4','14402'=>'Item5','14402'=>'Item9' );

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  The question title seems to imply that you are looking for an algorithm, but there is insufficient information about the input data to give an accurate answer.  Is the input a single string?  Is it an array containing strings?  Please include the actual data structures you use in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't know what you you want. You can easy receive such result'

```
$arr = [
[14400,Item1],
[14400,Item4],
[14401,Item2],
[14402,Item4],
[14402,Item5],
[14402,Item9]
];

$new = [];
foreach($arr as $item) 
  $new[$item[0]][] = $item[1];

print_r($new);
```

result

```
Array
(
[14400] => Array
        (
        [0] => Item1
        [1] => Item4
    )

[14401] => Array
    (
        [0] => Item2
    )

[14402] => Array
    (
        [0] => Item4
        [1] => Item5
        [2] => Item9
    )
)
```

Comment: Oh ... right - that is so easy and clear seeing it now. I guess I need to continue tomorrow - too many hours today.
Thanks a lot for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map of (int -> string list)

```
for each (key,value) pair
    map.get(key).add(value)
```

What language are you using?